# how to receive from the web service a list of objects from a linq query?

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql

i have a webservice that uses linq to sql to populate a list of objects from the result:

```
linqDBContext db = new linqDBContext();

public List<lut_flavorName> GetFlavors()
{
   List<lut_flavorName> results =
        (from a in db.lut_flavorNames
         select a).ToList();

   return results;
}
```

in the completed event, im trying to receive that into an observable collection (or even a typical list for that matter)

```
client.GetFlavorsCompleted += delegate(object s, GetFlavorsCompletedEventArgs es)
{
    ObservableCollection<Object> list = es.Result;

    //more code
};
```

The error that I'm getting is that I can't implicity convert from ArrayOfXElement to ObservableCollection

I tried casting but it still says it cannot convert. I'm assuming that instead of getting an object type "lut_flavorNames" i'm getting ArrayOfXElement because the silverlight project has no reference to the data context. How do I solve this? Is the problem caused by the fact that I'm using linq-to-sql instead of linq-to-entities or is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You service returns a `List<lut_flavorName>` which the service proxy treats as a `lut_flavorName[]`, not an `ObservableCollection`, so of course it will not cast.

Why not create a new `ObservableCollection` and add the list [via this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx)?

### e.g.

```
client.GetFlavorsCompleted += delegate(object s, GetFlavorsCompletedEventArgs es)
{
    ObservableCollection<Object> list = new ObservableCollection<Object>(es.Result);

    //more code
};
```

Note: most services really only need to return an IQuerable (lets you do server-side paging) or an IEnumerable.